# Need help finding smallest possible 8 digit 7 Segment LCD TN Display

Tags: lcd, 7segmentdisplay

I can find a number of LCD TN 8 digit 7 segment displays but they are far to big. The kind of size I'm looking for is the ones you usually find in mini calculators.

The size im looking for is around 10mm by 50mm. The smaller the better really. The other specs of the LCD are not really important at this time other than getting the smallest possible. Maybe I'm wrong in my search for an TN LCD?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Scott

Comment: Would it really be 8 digit if it is an LCD wouldn't that be LED?

Comment: No I am looking for LCD not LED. Unless you can find what I'm asking in LED format with low power consumption.

Comment: LCD power consumption will always be orders of magnitude lower than LED, regardless of how many superlatives they add to "low power" LED display.

Answer (score 2):

The [Densitron DG-067](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/pdf-datasheets/Datasheets-316/624780.html) package is 38 mm wide x 15.2 mm high.  The viewing area is 34 mm x 12.1 mm.  The characters are 6 mm (1/4") high.

BTW the datasheet doesn't mention TN, but [this page](http://www.densitron.com/displays/segmented_lcd_glass.aspx) where it is listed is titled "LCD Glass, Segmented Glass, TN Glass"

Comment: [Zebra connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_connector), for better or worse.

Comment: Thanks this hits the size requirements but where can I buy this? I've tried searching for the model and no sellers are popping up. Plus the zebra connection is a bit pants...

Comment: according to Densitron's website, they have both a rep and sales office in the UK: 
2001 Electronic Components Ltd,
Eastman Way,
Stevenage Business Park,
Pin Green,
Stevenage Hertfordshire SG1 4SZ UK,
Telephone: +44 1438 742001,
Fax: +44 1438 742002,
k.bull@2k1.co.uk, 
www.2k1.co.uk; 
sales office:  Densitron Europe Ltd,
5th Floor,
145 Cannon Street,
London EC4N 5BP,
Tel: +44 20 7648 4200,
Fax: +44 20 7648 4201,
sales@densitron.co.uk, 
www.densitron.com

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for exactly the same thing!

Here are some the smallest I could find - all about 10mm high digits...

---

[image] Availble for about $1.50 on Alibaba.

https://goodlcd.en.alibaba.com/product/1446136031-220673403/8_digits_LCD_module_manufacture_8_digits_LCD_glass.html?spm=a2700.7803228.1998738836.186.XE7yQV

---

[image]
Available for $3.16 on AliExpress.

https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/66PIN-TN-Positive-8-digits-Segment-LCD-Panel-3-0V-5-0V-Without-Backlight/224898_32602056642.html

---

[image]

$4.38 on Digikey

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/varitronix/VIM-878-DP-RC-S-HV/153-1114-ND/1118604